# Pinescript issue indexing variable in IF statement

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to index a variable so it only triggers up to a max of 5 times after the initial condition is met. I am having issues with the if statement. Here is a tradingview screenshot link of the objective https://www.tradingview.com/x/JimOkiQO/

```
redcon = x > high and open[1] < out1[1]

var counter = 0
red = redcon
if not (high > out2 and low < out2) and not (high > out3 and low < out3)
    redcon 
    red := redcon
    for i = -5 to 0 by 1 
        counter := counter[abs(i-1)]
        if counter == 0
            red != redcon
            break

barcolor(red ? color.yellow : na)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Why do you need a for loop here?

Comment: @BarisYakut thought the for loop would be the easiest way to count how many times the condition has been met because the max amount of times I want it to trigger is 5 times.

Comment: What are you triggering here? What is your strategy/goal with this indicator? Do you want to know how many times this `if not (high > out2 and low < out2) and not (high > out3 and low < out3)` condition is met? Maybe explain your goal a little bit more so we can help you.

Comment: @BarisYakut Thank you for the quick response. The order of operations are as follows. The moving average crosses over which is "redcon". The moving average cross over does not fire in a sideways market which is the "if not statement" Once the condition occurs where the moving average cross over happens "redcon" then I am trying to change the bar color on the proceeding pull backs to the moving average crossover where price crosses and closes above the moving average.- finishing in my next comment because of character limits

Comment: @BarisYakut Continued:  I am trying to set a max number of times it will register a pullback after a moving average crossover that price crosses and closes above the moving average to 5 because signals that happen after the 5th pullback to the moving average are much less reliable.

Comment: @BarisYakut here is a tradingview screenshot link to visualize it. https://www.tradingview.com/x/JimOkiQO/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a loop is a bad practice
Set a var that you update once your conditions are validated

Here is an example

```
// © LucemAnb

//@version=4
study("PullBack Limit", overlay=true)

max_pullbacks = 5

pull = ema(close, 21)
trend = ema(close, 100)

plot(pull, "Pull", color.blue, 2)
plot(trend, "Trend", pull>trend ? color.teal : color.maroon, 2)

var pullbacks = 0

long_pullback = crossunder(low, pull) and pull > trend
short_pullback = crossover(high, pull) and pull < trend

if long_pullback or short_pullback
    pullbacks := pullbacks + 1

if cross(pull, trend)
    pullbacks := 0

bgcolor( pullbacks < max_pullbacks ? ( long_pullback ? color.purple : short_pullback ? color.yellow : na) : na )
```

The pullbacks will stop being shown once the maximum specified limit is reached

Comment: Thank you for the help. It's much appreciated.